# Online compiler vs native compiler

Tags: java, online-compilation

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Count {
       public static void main(String []args){
       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
       int i=s.nextInt();
       int j=i+1;
       System.out.println(j);
    }

}
```

It's basic code in java,When i ran it on my own PC it worked fine,The same code i compiled and executed on [Online compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) ,it gives some error why??

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Count.main(Count.java:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [field](http://www.compileonline.com/stdin_input.php) for giving input arguments to STDIN.

> During your program you may ask user to input some values in the form
>   of number or strings. Because on the web we can not give interactive
>   option to provide input, so we provided this option to provide all the
>   inputs in one line which will be read by your program using different
>   functions available in your programming language.

[image]

Comment: Do you know why if you use 0 as input value it's throws the same exception, meanwhile using 00 it works? Just curiosity

Comment: @eltabo Hmm, no I don't know :/ This might be a bug. You can use http://ideone.com/ and provide arguments by the same way, it works here.

Comment: I supposed it was a bug. It just seems to me a little weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not provide any input for System.in. If you type something, say 2, in the "STDIN Input" box of that online compiler, your program works as expected.